# Given Probability

Tags: probability

When run, a computer program chooses the word "expensive'' with probability 2/3 and otherwise chooses the word "free''. It then selects a letter uniformly at random from the word it chose and outputs that letter. Given the program outputs "e'', what is the probability that it chose the word "free''?

The answer is 3/7 but I couldn't come up with this. I got a 1/5. Could anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The probability that the program chose `expensive` and then an E is $\frac23×\frac39=\frac29$. The probability of the same, but having chosen `free` first, is $\frac13×\frac24=\frac16$. By total probability, the desired result is
$$\frac{1/6}{2/9+1/6}=\frac37$$

Comment: Okay I got it. Thanks for your help :)